# shift and fn(alt) state in physical keyboard

Tags: android, keyevent, ime, android-hardware-keyboard

i need to know the state of shift and fn(alt) on physical keyboard when they are pressed or get locked.

i know the `KeyEvent` class have methods like `isAltPressed()` and `isShiftPressed()`, this works fine when shift or fn pressed one time, but when they pressed twice and get locked  i can not find out if this key is locked or not.

also the `getMetaState()` return **0** when shift or fn is locked and i press another key like **p**

so is there any method like `isShiftLocked()` or `isAltLocked()` or something like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since there is no method that do this for me i must keep track of shift and fn manually. when `onKeyDown()` method get called, i can check for shift or fn `keycode` and if they pressed, boolean variables such as `shiftPressed` or `shiftLocked` will be updated.